# Using insertable and updateable as false in hibernate for many-to-one mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

As per [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html), in below example:

```
<class name="Customer">
   <composite-id name="id" class="CustomerId">
      <key-property name="firstName" column="userfirstname_fk"/>
      <key-property name="lastName" column="userfirstname_fk"/>
      <key-property name="customerNumber"/>
   </composite-id>

   <property name="preferredCustomer"/>

   <many-to-one name="user">
      <column name="userfirstname_fk" updatable="false" insertable="false"/>
      <column name="userlastname_fk" updatable="false" insertable="false"/>
   </many-to-one>
</class>

<class name="User">
   <composite-id name="id" class="UserId">
      <key-property name="firstName"/>
      <key-property name="lastName"/>
   </composite-id>

   <property name="age"/>
</class>
```

> Notice a few things in the previous example:
>
> the order of the properties (and column) matters. It must be the same between the association and the primary key of the associated entity
>
> the many to one uses the same columns as the primary key and thus must be marked as read only (insertable and updatable to false).
>
> unlike with @MapsId, the id value of the associated entity is not transparently copied, check the foreign id generator for more information.

I am new to Hibernate so finding it difficulty in understanding these.

- Why the order of the properties is matters? Which is called as association and which one is associated in first statement?
- Why the columns needs to be set as false for insertable and updateable?
- What is copying transparently? How @MapId makes a difference here?

Can someone please help me in clarifying these.